# MVC 4 Portable Areas CSS/JS minification

Tags: asp.net-mvc, minify, portable-areas

I used MVC 3 + Contrib Project PortableAreas to split my web to multiple projects.
Now I moved to MVC 4 and want to use new feature minification for my css and JS.

But when I do:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/DSB/Styles/CSS")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/common/js")" type="text/javascript">
```

instead of:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/DSB/Styles/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/common/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/common/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

it does not work.
How to use bundling/minification in Portable areas?

thanks

Comment: a side note 
in "Mvc 4" a url like `~/Content/site.css` will be translated automatically to `Url.Content()`

so in your code you don't need all the `Url.Content` just write the raw url

Comment: I know this is an old question, did you find a working solution? Kind of a personal opinion: portable area content is already pushed into dll as embedded resource, you have to recompile it on any modification, so why not minify JS and CSS before compilation? Try chirpy: http://chirpy.codeplex.com/, and only add your already minified JS+CSS to the dll.

Comment: No I didn't. The problem with your sollution is I need to add another library to my project. I went for MVC4 because I want to remove some of them. Not to add additionl. But thanks

Comment: I think the problem here is that you try to import folders. As far as I know, this only works if you make whats called a bundle. I am no expert in how to do this, so you should just google it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the bundling and minification does not foresee handling anything else than actual files. I have 2 solutions here that work.

Extract the files into temp files - requires write privileges for a folder within the app. [Here](https://gist.github.com/4250921) is the code to handle that. It uses a directory called "Static" as the temporary target path. You can use it like this:

```
bundles.Add(new Rebundler(assemblyWithPortableArea, "~/VirtualPathUsedForResource")
                .Include("Fully.Qualified.Embeded.Resource.Name", "other...")
                .Rebundle());
```

Using it in a template is exaxctly as if you would use it in a non portable app, so @Scripts.Render() or @Styles.Render()

The other solution involves creating a bunch of classes that will allow you to use embeded resources. [Here](https://gist.github.com/4250979) is the base class, and here are the [script](https://gist.github.com/4250990) and [style](https://gist.github.com/4250994) bundles. Here's the usage:

```
bundles.Add(new EmbededStyleBundle(assemblyWithPortableArea, "~/VirtualPathUsedForResource")
                .Include("~/AreaName/Content/themes/custom/jquery-ui.css"));
```

With this approach, you need to use [this](https://gist.github.com/4251065) class to render the resources. So instead of using the @Scripts.Render() or @Styles.Render() the template code looks like this:

```
@Assets.RenderStyles("virtual path here")
@Assets.RenderScripts("virtual path here")
```

Note that this code is far from clean. It has been mostly reverse engineered and may skip a few paths, but it seems to work so far.

Comment: this works when web.config debug="false" or BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;  In day to day debugging the script is not rendered - probably because files.Add(new FileInfo(resourceName)); doesn't exist. I guess RenderScripts removes not found files - do you have a fix for this?  I tried using route to embedded resource through route defined in mvccontrib /AreaName/Scripts/file.js   /AreaName/Styles/file.css - following convention /Content/Styles/file.css, /Content/Scripts/file.js  in assembly - however that didn't fix it either.